# which statement will execute first insert or update in sql

Tags: sql

```
Select * from emp where id =10
update emp set sal = 10000 where id = 10
```

if we run these 2 query at a same time by different users, which will execute 1st and why?

Thanks,

Comment: `Select` is not an `Insert`.

Comment: There is no *the same time*. One query will come first, if only a nanosecond

Comment: You should make it clear if you mean if the two users run the same set ('batch') of commands, or if one user runs the select while the other runs the update?

Comment: One user running the update and another running select at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no priority based on command (select/update). The first query will depend on earlier request sent to SQL server. In all cases the SQL server or TCP stack accept the request of one of users and his/her query will run first.